# Can running npm run build to React App or ng build --prod to angular app Inject Clickjacking?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, malware, clickjacking

I started development of my website in Angular 9.1 and build the application via ng build --prod,
After build there were four js files generated and these js file will be referred in index.html.

1. a main.*.js
2. a runtime.*.js
3. 2 polyfill.*.js

I used to upload all my website content to aws static website hosting and then the play begins.
When I refresh my website a clickjacking will be injected and any click to my website will take me to some random website for advertisement display.
What I have noticed is, my runtime.*.js is **getting modified** between my upload to AWS S3 bucket i.e At my local My runtime.*.js is completely normal but when It is accessed in browser after upload, it will have the malware injected.

Since I was not having idea that how is this happening I doubted,

1. npm
2. any npm library
3. nodejs

Hence to confirm that I started development in ReactJS but the result was same after uploading my website to AWS.

What else I tried is I renamed all the js file with x.js, y.js.... but still that script was getting injected.
Now I am not getting any clue that how the script is getting injected in my normal js file.
As per me only one area I can doubt

1. **AWS**?
   To further experiment I removed public read access to all my objects but still that Script was loading (only that script) else every other objects were in-accessible and that strengthen my doubt.
   Can somebody here please help me to get my website up and running without malware/clickjacking.

This whole runtime.*.js is modified.

[image]